How to get original argv[0] in shebang interpreter
I'm writing a program that's intended to be used as a shebang interpreter
#!/usr/bin/my-program
# some-file

When I execute some-file my program is executed with argv[0] = /usr/bin/my-program and argv[1] = /path/to/some-file but I cannot find the original argv[0] "some-file". Even if I execute as exec -a fake some-file, or execv("some-file", ["fake"]) argv[0] is always my program, and I cannot find fake anywhere.
To test I wrote a simple program that prints argv
#include <stdio.h>
// print-args.c
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
  }
}

gcc print-args.c -o print-args
echo "#!$PWD/print-args" > test-shebang
chmod +x test-shebang 
strace -e trace=process -f --argv0 fake ./test-shebang

execve("./test-shebang", ["fake", "a"], 0x7ffc76487480 /* 64 vars */) = 0
argv[0]: path/to/print-args
argv[1]: ./test-shebang

I also checked /proc/self/cmdline but that also has  the same argv array.

The original argv[0] gets skipped for shebang scripts, at least in Linux. Linux also supports "miscellaneous binary formats" that can be configured to preserve the original argv[0].

The results seem to depend on the platform.
On a MacBook Pro (running macOS Sequoia 15.1.1 — but I've seen the same behaviour in earlier versions), my command alev (analogous to your program, but printing out the environment too), was specified in a script x3.shconsisting of one line of code:
#!/Users/jleffler/src/cmd/alev

When run from a different directory, it produced the original script as argv[1].  At the time, ~- (aka $OLDPWD) was /Users/jleffler/src/cmd, which is the directory where both alev and the script were stored.
$ ~-/x3.sh a 'b c' '  d  e  f  '
argv[0] = <</Users/jleffler/src/cmd/alev>>
argv[1] = <</Users/jleffler/src/cmd/x3.sh>>
argv[2] = <<a>>
argv[3] = <<b c>>
argv[4] = <<  d  e  f  >>
envp[0] = <<MANPATH=/Users/jleffler/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man>>
envp[1] = <<DBEDIT=vim>>
…
envp[13] = <<OLDPWD=/Users/jleffler/src/cmd>>
…
envp[27] = <<PWD=/Users/jleffler/src/spelling-bee/2024-12-07>>
…
envp[42] = <<HISTTIMEFORMAT=%F %T:>>
envp[43] = <<HISTFILE=/Users/jleffler/.bash.jleffler>>
envp[44] = <<_=/Users/jleffler/src/cmd/x3.sh>>

Normally, x3.sh would be on my PATH; this one is not, hence the pathname needed to run it.
If Linux doesn't do that, then this is a difference between macOS (and probably other BSD-based systems) and Linux, of which I was previously unaware.
I have occasionally used a shebang like:
#!/Users/jleffler/bin/program -f
…
# Code interpreted by program -f script-file
…

This runs program -f script-file (plus any command line arguments) — on macOS, anyway.
